# How to get Chrome's vintage audit panel in 2017? (How to use Chrome's Audit tool to remove unused CSS?)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to follow this tutorial that was written back in 2014: https://www.labnol.org/internet/remove-unused-css/28635/.

It says there should be a `Remove unused CSS rules` section that appears after running an "audit" in the devtools.

I'm currently using Chrome 60.0.3112.90 on Windows and there is no such section. It's not even in the [specs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/blocking-resources).  Was it replaced by `Reduce render-blocking stylesheets`? If yes, how is it the same?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I also see there isn't the option there once was in Chrome.

Comment: @WebGuy Yes! See the answer!

Comment: Wow, i searched and searched but never found anyone that mentioned this.  It worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get the old audit panel:

1. Open developer tools at first by pressing f12 or Ctrl + Shift + I
2. Open the Command Menu (Cmd+Shift+P (or Ctrl+Shift+P)).
3. Start typing "Legacy".
4. Select "Show Legacy Audits".

Comment: If you're trying this and it's opening the Print menu, hit F12 first to open the dev tools then run the command listed above.

Comment: After this how do you remove those unused CSS? Or do we get to copy only the used CSS?

Comment: @JikkuJose  Have you tried the tutorial I linked in the question?

Comment: Yes, I did. But that only shows you the unused CSS. I was hoping there was a way to select/save only the required css?

Comment: As of Mar 2019, this no longer works. See Kendra's answer below for a solution that does.

Answer (score 13):

Since chrome has updated, you now need to use CSS and JS code **coverage**.
Find unused CSS and JS code with the new Coverage tab. When you load or run a page, the tab tells you how much code was used, versus how much was loaded. You can reduce the size of your pages by only shipping the code that you need.

**The Coverage tab**
Figure 1. The Coverage tab
Clicking on a URL reveals that file in the Sources panel with a breakdown of which lines of code executed.

There is a breakdown of code coverage in the Sources panel.
Each line of code is color-coded:

Solid green means that line of code executed.
Solid red means it did not execute.
A line of code that is both red and green, means that only some code on that line executed. For example, a ternary expression like var b = (a > 0) ? a : 0 is colored both red and green.
Note: The color-coding is likely to change in future Chrome releases.
To open the Coverage tab:

Open the Command Menu. (`cmd + shift + p`)

Start typing Coverage and select Show Coverage.

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. But is there also a way to remove all red marked lines on one click? So that I have only the the used code.